# I need to check if a string is a pangram string or not is my code correct?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, pangram

```
public static class Inova
{
    public static bool IsPangram(string str)
    {
        int compteur = 26;

        for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length; i++)
        {

            if (('A' <= str[i] && str[i] <= 'Z') || ('a' <= str[i] && str[i] <= 'z'))
            {
                for (int j = str[i + 1]; j <= str.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (compteur != 0 && str[i] != str[j])
                    {
                        compteur = compteur - 1;
                    }
                }

            }

            if (compteur == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things incorrect:

- `for (int j = str[i + 1]; j <= str.Length; j++)`
  this does not do what you think, it will convert the next char to an `int`, you want to loop all letters until end, beginning from the current letter + 1.
- The `if` ... `else` belong to the end of the method, outside of the loop, otherwise you return `false` after the first iteration in the `for`-loop

So you want to know if it's a perfect pangram? First we need to say what a [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) is: *a sentence containing every letter of the alphabet.* It seems you want to check if it's even a perfect pangram, so every letter should appear exactly once. Here is a method not using any fancy LINQ(which might not be allowed) that supports perfect/imperfect pangrams:

```
public static class Inova
{
    private const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   
    public static bool IsPangram(string str, bool mustBePerfect)
    {
        HashSet<char> remaingLetters = new HashSet<char>(alphabet);
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            char letter = char.ToUpperInvariant(c);
            if (!alphabet.Contains(letter)) continue;
            bool repeatingLetter = !remaingLetters.Remove(letter);
            if (mustBePerfect && repeatingLetter)
            {
                return false; // already removed
            }
        }

        return remaingLetters.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bool isPangram = Inova.IsPangram("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyZZ", false);
```

Since z appears twice this method returns `false` for perfect and `true` for not perfect.

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gEXuvG

Side-note: i wanted to keep it simple, if you want you can still improve it. You can return `true` in the loop: `if(!mustBePerfect && remaingLetters.Count == 0) return true`.

Answer (score 1):

I would check for existence of each letter in the string, so

```cs
public static bool IsPangram(string str) {

  str = str.ToLower();

  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

    char c = Convert.ToChar(i + 97);

    if (!str.Contains(c)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


Console.WriteLine(IsPangram("hello world"));
Console.WriteLine(IsPangram("abcdefghi jkl mno pqrstuvwxyz"));

// output:
False
True
```